# SSIS data flow validation failure on snapshot read

Tags: sql-server, ssis, snapshot

I have two database snapshots of the same source DB on my server with sql server 2008 R2. One of them is corrupted (marked suspect). My ETL does not read the corrupted one but is still failing validation for a data flow task when it is reading a view hosted on the good snapshot. The good snapshot does not refer to any entities in the corrupted DB snapshot. Is there any reason for this happening?

Error Code -

Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Database 'XXXXX_SS' cannot be opened. It has been marked SUSPECT by recovery. See the SQL Server errorlog for more information.

Error Log
The operating system returned error 665(The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation) to SQL Server during a write at offset 0x000011579d6000 in file 'X:\X\XXXXX_4NSS.ss'.

Comment: Whats the actual error? Can you select from the view in SSMS or get a definition (script as alter)

Comment: I can select from the view in ssms and get a definition, only in ssis i get a validation error when trying to use the view in a data flow task. My scheduled ETL jobs are also failing. The corrupted snapshot DB is not used in any connection string in the package.

Comment: @SQLMonsta, you might try running a SQL Trace during package initialization to see what SQL statements SSIS is executing for meta-data validation.  It seem the bad snapshot is being touched during this process.  The easiest workaround would be to drop the corrupted snapshot.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the validation error, i.e. the text that matters in the error message.

Comment: @DanGuzman Dropping the corrupted snapshot did get the process to run okay but was curious about the error. I will try the trace to see if there is something in the package validation step that is hitting the corrupted DB - Thanks.

Comment: Your error definitely implies that you're connecting to a faulty database. I suggesting you temporarily rename the "Good" database and reconfigure your package just to verify  which database you are really connecting to. I suspect you are indeed connecting to the faulty one and you will continue to get a message saying "XXXXX_SS' cannot be opened" (rather than "GoodDatabase cannot be opened"